# Surface temperature when outside solar system

Tags: solar-system, temperature

Suppose Earth has drifted away from solar system for some reason. It has been 320 years since drifting started. For almost 250 years, it is farther away from Neptune. 
- How cold would the surface temperature be? 
- Would it effect the inner temperature? (The "1 degrees centigrade per 33 meters" principle)

Comment: Good Question. I'm not a physicist or anything, so I can't answer that question, but the earth's surface would get a lot colder, and everybody wolf died by 250 years-probably a day.

Comment: I am carrying everybody down. I need to know how deep is necessary. Would it go down to -270 C on surface? If so I need to go down to 10km.

Comment: can you clarify the details please ? did it take 70 (ie. 320-250) years to drift in a spiral line from current orbit to neptune's orbit ? and then another 250 years of drifting at the same rate past neptune's orbit ? Does it stay on the ecliptic ? how does it avoid capture or collision with large mass bodies like Jupiter or Saturn ?

Comment: @UKS I told you, I don't know. Just look up Surface Temperature of Pluto, find its coldest point, and use it. That should probably work.

Comment: Hi John, please assume, somehow a dead rogue star drifted Earth away and it totally left the solar system. The point is, almost no Sun for over 250 years.

Comment: I imagine that where magma comes to the surface you will not have to go down too deep. Try geothermal energy, Iceland for example.

Answer (score 4):

There's a sketch of an answer [here](http://www.popsci.com/node/204957)

Basically, at 320 years, there hasn't been time to freeze the planet properly. The oceans won't be frozen solid yet, and I suspect that the atmosphere would not be raining out yet.  Based on [borehole climatology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(climate)#Boreholes), I'd guesstimate that you'd need to be perhaps 100-200 meters down to be able to ignore it, at this stage.

The gradual progression of ocean freezing, the need to go deeper and the freeze-out of the atmosphere would all be interesting, though.

Comment: With Earth's size, its internal heat sources, significant atmosphere for a terrestrial planet, and moon with its tidal heating I don't think the nitrogen, oxygen or argon components would ever freeze out.